# Передать объект из JS в PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Как передать объект почему не получается? Что я не так делаю?
JS:

```
   <script>
    function doIt(){
        VK.api("users.get", {fields: "photo_100,photo_200,counters,city,status,bdate,career,sex"}, function(data) {                
            for(c=0;c<data.response.length;c++){
                $("body").append("<img src='"+data.response[c].photo_100+"'><br><br>");
                var myData = data.response;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test2.php",
                    data:myData,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success:function(response){

                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        doIt();

    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_POST['myData']) {
$param = json_decode($_POST['myData']);

 echo json_encode($param);
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откуда у Вас в `$_POST` возьмется ключ `myData`?

```
                data: { myData: data.response[c] },
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: @Sergey Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Смотрел бегло. Тебе на сервер приходит содержимое myData (без обертки этим названием). Если у тебя содержится в var myData какие-то данные, обращайся к ним сразу напрямую. Например, если есть myData.id - то на сервере получай его через $_POST['id']. myData в $_POST не будет